# What is the result of this limit if it exists?

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} 10^{-x}$$

Is the value of this limit 0, or an infinitesimal number, whose definition is $0 < y < (z \in \mathbb{R})$, where $z$ is any real number, and $y$ is the infinitesimal number (also real)?

Is it possible that this limit doesn't exist? If it doesn't, then why?

Comment: Yes, the limit is zero, but why??

Comment: @imranfat To imagine how this limit may work, I imagine the number 10 being multiplied by $\frac{1}{10}$ repeatedly. You add zeroes before the $1$ and after the decimal point. For this reason, it seems to me that the distance to zero is never fully covered. Is this a wrong way to look at it?

Comment: No, it is not wrong to look at it that way, because indeed, as $x$ goes up as an integer, the outcomes "loses" a decimal. But it is not very formal either. Remember that $x$ is any real number. So you need a little more than that to conclude that the limit is zero

Comment: @imranfat Actually, would a good way to think about this be through the limit of $1/x$? I can see why this limit is 0, and considering that the only difference between these 2 limits is the rate of the approach, then the limits are practically the same, no? That's kind of what E. Joseph points out

Comment: You have to look up the definition of limit. Whatever distance you pick there is n after which all of the members are in less distance than you picked

Comment: Yes, that is one way of showing the limit is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} 10^{-x}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac 1{10^x}\leqslant \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac 1x=0.$$

So yes the limit exists, and yes it is $0$.

Comment: this doesn't really clarify the question